# How to plot only a selected number of rows in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, linegraph

I am trying to plot only the first 220 rows out of the 260 in my data frame from the first and third column.

This is a "slice" of the data frame. I am trying not to include the "Average", "Pre.Covid" and "Change" rows in the ggplot2 code.

```
structure(list(Date = c("01-2019", "01-2019", "01-2019", "01-2019", 
                    "01-2019", "Average", "Pre.Covid","Change"),
          Region = c("South East", "South West", "London", "East of England", 
          "East Midlands", "West Midlands", "Yorkshire and The Humber", 
          "North West"),
          Unemployment.rate = c("3.13", "2.916523", "4.210277", 
                     "3.194942", "4.682473", "5.070812", "5.231136", "3.607693")), 
      row.names = c(NA, -260L), 
      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried using the code below,

```
ggplot(df, aes(df[1:220,1], df[1:220,3], color = Region, group = Region)) +
            geom_line() +
            labs(x = "Date", y = "Unemployment rate (%)")
```

However, I get the following error message(s):

*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.*

*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.* (yes, twice)

*Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'*

Any idea how to work around that?
Also, if anyone could please let me know how to change those numerical values into percentages with 2 decimals it would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: please debug your dput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the dataframe before plotting without changing `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df[1:220, ], 
       aes(Date, Unemployment.rate, color = Region, group = Region)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Unemployment rate (%)")
```